# access 2010 writing SQL statements

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am writing SQL statements in Access 2010 for my homework. What I am trying to do is `Display the Client Number, Client Name, Bookkeeper Number, First Name, and Last Name for
all clients. Sort the records in ascending order by bookkeeper number and client number`. That is what the question is asking me. But when i go to write the statement, I am receiving an error saying that the bookkeeper number could refer to more than one table in the from clause. How could I get around this?

This is what I tried so far

```
select C.[client number], C.[client name], C.[bookkeeper number], B.[firstname]
from [client] C, [bookkeeper] B
order by [bookkeeper number], [client number] ASC;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the error, just add a `B.` in the `order by` like this: `B.[bookkeeper number]`.

However to get the correct results you will also have to add a INNER JOIN clause between the two tables.

Comment: wow, i totally missed that one. thank you very much for your help. something so simple, and it was taking me forever to figure out. thanks again for your help

Comment: My pleasure. The best thanks, of course, is a vote and an answer acceptance.